# Scala traits mixin order and super call

Tags: scala, mixins, traits, linearization

I have this code:

```
trait base{
  def msg: Unit= {
    println{"base"}
  }
}

trait foo extends base {
  abstract override def msg: Unit ={
    super.msg
    println("foo")
  }
}

class base2{
  def msg:Unit = {
    println{"base 2"}
  }
}

class test extends base2 with foo{
   override def msg: Unit ={
    super.msg
    println("done")
  }
}
```

If I call `(new test).msg`, this prints out things like: `base, foo, done`

However, if I change the base trait to:

```
trait base{
  def msg: Unit
}
```

it prints out things like: `base 2, foo, done`

I understand the order of `with` is from right to left (last one comes first) but how about `extends`? How come sometimes it prints `base2`, but sometimes `base`?

Comment: This kind of weirdness is why I avoid the cake pattern.

Comment: If it works like in Groovy, then you need to add `super.msg` to `base` trait, so it chains to your `base2` class. Without having implementation in `base`, `base2` is called via `foo`'s `super.msg`.

Answer (score 1):

When you omit the implementation, `base` is a *template of a trait* and has different evaluation rules. See the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#example)

Answer (score 1):

Scala has something called type linearization. It defines initialization order. Read here http://eed3si9n.com/constraining-class-linearization-in-Scala