# Meaning of super in stacked traits depends on call site?

Tags: scala, inheritance, super, traits

I can't come up with a very good description of this in words, so, please take a look at this example:

```
trait Base { def foo = "Base" }
trait One extends Base { override def foo = "One <: " + super.foo }
trait Two extends Base { override def foo = "Two <: " + super.foo }

new Base with One with Two {} foo
```

This prints: `Two <: One <: Base`, which is what I expect.
Now, I am trying to add another level, so that overriding traits would not have to call `super` explicitly. Like this:

```
trait Base { def foo = "Base" }
trait Foo extends Base { def bar = foo + " <: " + super.foo }
trait One extends Foo { override def foo = "One" }
trait Two extends Foo { override def foo = "Two" }

new Foo with One with Two {} bar
```

Here, the last line prints out `Two <: Base`

So, it looks like in the first example `super` means `One`, while in the last one it skips `One` and goes directly to `Base`.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't behavior be the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694600/behaviour-of-super-in-chained-scala-traits and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569901/scala-traits-mixin-order-and-super-call might end up being helpful.

Comment: I don't see the relation again: the first one is just a confusion about an overriden function call, and the other one is abstract template vs. concrete imlementation ...

Comment: I think the latter will be a clue, as traits are never concrete.

Comment: @RobStarling not "traits", _methods_. That question is about differences  in handling inheritance with abstract vs. concrete _method_ implementation in the base trait. Interesting read, but different from issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st case, `new Base with One with Two {} foo` (which is the same as `new One with Two {} foo`), the "trait stack" is pretty obvious. The `Two` has a `foo` which calls the `foo` of its super (`One`) which calls the `foo` of its super (`Base`).

In the 2nd case, `new Foo with One with Two {} bar` (which is the same as `new One with Two {} bar`), the "trait stack" is Base->Foo->One->Two.  You call `bar` but `Two` has no `bar` and `One` has no `bar`.  `Foo` has a `bar` that calls the `foo` of its super (`Base`).

**UPDATE**

Consider this mod as @Dima has proposed.

```
trait Base { def foo = "Base" }
trait Foo extends Base { def bar = foo + " <: " + super.foo }
trait One extends Foo { override def bar = super.bar
                        override def foo = "One" }
trait Two extends Foo { override def bar = super.bar
                        override def foo = "Two" }

new One with Two {} bar  // no Base or Foo needed
```

Yes, this gives the same output as before: `res0: String = Two <: Base`

Now `Two` calls the `bar` of its super(`One`) which calls the `bar` of its super (`Foo`) which calls the `foo` (not `bar`) of its super.

All this `bar` activity is separate from the `foo` definitions.  `Two` never invokes the `foo` of its super so the `One.foo` is never used and cannot be a part of the output.

**A DIFFERENT APPROACH**

Consider the following.

```
trait B { def id = "B" } // B for Base

trait V extends B { override def id = "V" }
trait W extends B { override def id = "W" }
trait X extends B { override def id = "X" }
trait Y extends B { override def id = "Y" }
trait Z extends B { override def id = "Z" }

trait R extends B { override def id = "R"; def mySup = super.id } // Required
```

Now try instantiating this in multiple different ways.

```
val r = new V with Y with W with R with X {} // B not needed
// or
val r = new W with R with Z with X with V {}
// or
val r = new R with Y with V with B with W {}
// or
val r = new Z with Y with X with W with R {}
// etc.
```

In each case `r.id` will be the last trait in the chain and `r.mySup` will be the trait that comes before the `R` (or `B` if nothing is specified before the `R`).

Comment: Doesn't look like it. I added `override def bar = super.bar` to both `One`, and `Two`, so that your "but Two has no bar and One has no bar" is no longer the case, but it still shows the same behavior.

Comment: @jwvh: That does not really answer the question. If I may, here is how I understand Dima's puzzlement: if the call `super.foo` in `bar` (in the second case) resolves to `Base.foo`, then it seems to indicate that it is resolved statically/lexically, and not dynamically (which by linearization rules would resolve to `Two.foo`). But if that is true, then in the first case we'd similarly expect the call to `super.foo` in `Two.foo` to resolve to `Base.foo`, but here it does not, it **does** resolve to `One.foo`.

Comment: And no, it is not "the same as `new One with Two {} bar`": `new One with Two` don't even have bar ...

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, yes, this is exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, @Dima `super.foo` in `Two` is resolved to `One.foo` according to the linearization algorithm. What's wrong? In the second case `super` is resolved to `Base.foo` the same way, `foo` without super is called as a virtual method, which resolves to `Two.foo` (head of the linearization chain).

Answer (score 0):

`super.foo` in the `Foo` definition means `Base.foo` as that's the superclass of `Foo`, where the definition is. `super` is *not* a magical keyword that means "one superclass up from the final class".

Incidentally, you might also want to look into self-types. See [What is the difference between self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

Comment: Well, ok,  but why doesn't the same reasoning apply to the first example: `Base` is a superclass of `Two`, so why doesn't `super.foo` refer to `Base.foo` there?

Comment: I also don't see what this has to do with self-types. Can you clarify?

Comment: re: self-types, `trait One { self: Base => override def foo = "One <: " + super.foo }` is a way of writing a trait `One` that can only be used to extend a class that derives from `Base`.

Comment: I know :) That's not at all what I was trying to do though. 
The idea is to be able to combine ("_stack_") several traits extending `Base` into the same class: `class Foo with One with Two with Three with Four ...`, kinda like what I showed in my examples, except, in the first case it works as intended, and in the second case it does not.